# WPF Disabling DataGridCheckBoxColumn based on observable collection property

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, wpfdatagrid

I am a new WPF starter and am having trouble achieving a minor thing.

I have a viewModel that has an ObservableCollection
Order and that has two props

- IsSelected(to indicate that order has been selected in grid)
- EnableOrder(to indicate if an order can be selected).

However the checkbox is not disabled when Orders/EnableOrder is false.

```html
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Orders}">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Binding="{Binding IsSelected}">
                    <DataGridCheckBoxColumn.CellStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
                        <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="{Binding Orders/EnableOrder}" />
                    </Style>
                    </DataGridCheckBoxColumn.CellStyle>
                 </DataGridCheckBoxColumn>                
            </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

It works when I hard-code False like below

```html
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Orders}">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Binding="{Binding IsSelected}">
                    <DataGridCheckBoxColumn.CellStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
                        <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />
                    </Style>
                    </DataGridCheckBoxColumn.CellStyle>
                 </DataGridCheckBoxColumn>                
            </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Also I was not able to specify binding as below as EnableOrder is not visible in XAML intellisense.

```
<Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="{Binding EnableOrder}" />
```

Please note that there were other simple DataGridTextColumn bindings that I had inside the grid and the bindings worked without any problem

Comment: I would imagine that intellisense wouldn't pull up EnableOrder since you are in a Style and that Style may apply to multiple items which may have different DataContexts. So if you bind to EnableOrder even though there isn't any intellisense are you still able to build and run, and if so does it work?

Comment: Ignored the Intellisense and I was able to get it working.

Answer (score 1):

I think the binding was wrong. Check with below code. Also check the output window for any binding errors.

```
 <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Orders}">
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Binding="{Binding IsSelected}">
                        <DataGridCheckBoxColumn.CellStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
                            <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="{Binding EnableOrder}" />
                        </Style>
                        </DataGridCheckBoxColumn.CellStyle>
                     </DataGridCheckBoxColumn>                
                </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Copied Comment as Answer Since the OP Found it to Work:**

I would imagine that intellisense wouldn't pull up EnableOrder since you are in a Style and that Style may apply to multiple items which may have different DataContexts. So if you bind to EnableOrder even though there isn't any intellisense are you still able to build and run, and if so does it work?